# AngularJs ng-show, ng-model, Laravel Validation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel

i am new in AngularJs. Can you help me with the following problem.

I have checkbox

```
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="weekendPrice" id="weekendPriceCheck" name="weekendPriceCheck"> Special Weekend Price
</label>
<input type="text" ng-show="weekendPrice" id="weekendPrice" name="weekendPrice" class="form-control" placeholder="Weekend Price"  style="margin-top:20px;" value="{{ Request::old('weekendPrice') }}">
```

```
if('{{ Request::old('weekendPriceCheck') }}' == 'on') {
  $('#weekendPriceCheck').attr('ng-checked', 'true');
  $('#weekendPrice').show();
}
```

After validation i can return the value of weekend price by `{{ Request::old('weekendPrice') }}`.

Checkbox i can checked by `.attr('ng-checked','true')`.

But cant show the input. When i use .show by jquery its stay hided. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with `ng-init`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="weekendPrice" id="weekendPriceCheck" ng-init='weekendPrice='{{ Request::old('weekendPriceCheck') == "on" ? "true": "false"; }}'

name="weekendPriceCheck">
```